# Google Sign In API Exeption

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-signin

so i'm new to google sign in and I followed a tutorial and all seemed to work well, but when i test it i get the following error : **com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiExeption:10:**

If someone know please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, add SHA-1 key to your firebase project.
Here's how to generate one: https://protocoderspoint.com/generate-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate/

Comment: The thing is that i already put the SHA-1 fingerprint and it's still not working

Comment: Try re-adding it. Make sure you do not use the Android Studio (if you're using that) terminal. I used that once and the SHA-1 did not work.